# Wrong view size after updating to XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I updated XCode to versoin 8, when I opened `Main.storyboard` it showed me popup to choose device version, I chose `iPhone 6s` everything was converted but my views are still square size
[image]

And they doesn't change even I change device type:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me helped:

1. You need to find `Root View Controller`
2. Select main view
3. Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Update Frames